# Do you keep all files on GitHub after pushing, deleting and pushing again from local?

Tags: git, github

This may be a beginner question since I haven't interacted much with GitHub. But I wanted to know if the following workflow was possible

1. Push some files of a folder to GitHub
2. Delete those files from Local Machine
3. Push new files to the same GitHub folder
   All while keeping both the previous and newer files in the GitHub repo folder.

The reason for this workflow is because I am working with a lot of 15+ GB files and I'm running out of space locally. So I thought I could push those files to Git in chunks after I'm done working with them, delete them, get in new files, and then push them to the same place in Git again. In the end, I want all of my files on GitHub from the same folder, while they may/may not be on local. Is this possible?

Comment: No, this is not possible.

Comment: Okay, any other way it might be possible though? Can't find a way to store all the data I need for my project locally

Answer (score 3):

I think you shouldn't use git for 15GB+ files. Because git is designated for code hosting and work with plain text files. It is not powerful for storing files. It works, but for this you can use file storing services.

Comment: I'm not using it as a file storing service, I want to store the data along with the code I'm working on for a project

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically this is possible. But it's bad git practice as your local and your remote repo will be out of synch with each other. If this is for web development, I would definitely suggest using a service like AWS S3 or even Imgur. If these are large datasets, then I would suggest using a Database hosting service.

Comment: Got it. I'll be discarding the repo locally since, it's a temp project. Think I'll used GDrive for storage then

Comment: Glad I could be of help

Answer (score 1):

Git does not work with individual files, other than as part of *commits*, which contain a complete snapshot of the repository in a particular state. It also treats all copies of the repository - including the one on your local computer - as equal, and expects each one to contain a complete copy of the *entire history* of the repository. So even "permanently" deleting a large file in the current revision of your repository won't free up space.

Git is a source code versioning system, designed for use with large collections of small text files, generally no more than a few *kilobytes* in size. It does not have rich support for binary files, and is not at all suitable for files on the order of gigabytes.

There are plugins such as [git lfs](https://git-lfs.github.com/) which allow you to track versions of large files without storing them inside the repository itself. It is [supported by GitHub](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/working-with-files/managing-large-files/about-large-files-on-github) and other hosting providers.

Alternatively, separate your *data* from your *code*, and store the large files in a data store, referencing them dynamically in the code.

Comment: Yeah, I was looking into lfs, even that's got limits I saw. I'll try separating the data from the code. Thanks!